# Passing parameter with space to Shell Script using Java

Tags: java, linux, shell

I've had trouble passing parameters with spaces to a shell script with the following JAVA code:

```
List<String> parameterList = new ArrayList<String>();
parameterList.add(executable);
parameterList.add(inputFile);
parameterList.add(outputPath);

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(parameterList);
pb.redirectErrorStream();
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
}
```

The problem comes when passing my parameter to the 2nd add to the list in the input file variable.

If I use my bat file, I can get the string with spaces, say "my data.xml" using the variable %~1. However, in LINUX, I cannot use %~1 instead there is "$1" which does not accept strings with spaces. Is there a similar approach I can use that will allow me to pass parameters with spaces to a shell script?

EDIT:
In the console the command should go like this:
run.sh "/scratch/input/my data.xml" /scratch/output/

Is there a way to have the above command be called from JAVA verbatim?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean `"$1"` does not accept strings with spaces? Are you quoting it properly in your script? I'm guessing this question has actually nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Hi, I meant that in the shell script, I have "$1" instead of just $1. This is can be related to Java because I've tried to add the quotation marks via java by having parameterList.add("\"" + inputFile + "\"");

Comment: I've made the following simple script `echo "Input file=[$1] and output file=[$2]" >> test.out` using `/bin/bash` as interpretor, and I ran it using a snippet similar to yours even without escaping the arguments. Looking at *test.out* I can see `Input file=[input file] and output file=[output file]` so $1 and $2 are passed correctly. Can you show us the shell script and explain what problem you have encountered?

Comment: Hi, my shell script's first 2 lines:

export myextract="$1"
export output="$2/"

I pass a parametert that can have spaces to $1

Comment: Basically, I need to pass the following command to my my script [shellscript.sh "scratch/input/my data.xml" scratch/output] using java. I tried adding the quote marks using JAVA but it triggered an error.

Comment: Or I need an alternative to the windows %~1 which takes the first argument regardless of spaces.

Comment: Like I said, the arguments are passed correctly, including the space, to my sample script so I suspect your problem is elsewhere. What do you mean by `.. but it triggered an error`? Who did and what was the error? Also please use @username when replying so that people get notified of your new comments.

Comment: @Morfic I actually think it's an issue with the software my script is running. Thanks for the insight on the issue, we just resolved to remove all spaces because it's in linux.